# How to detect in which direction object whose movement is created with math.pingpong is moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to determine if my object is moving left or right. His movement is created with math.pingpong in vector 3.

I've seen some topics regarding same problem as I, but none of them have my type of movement code. I've tried to do it with rigidbody.velocity but I can't seem to do it right.

```
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
    public Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(14, 0, 0);


    public float speed = 1.0f;

    public bool isMoving;

    void Update()
    {
        moveEnemy();
    }

    void moveEnemy()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pos1, pos2, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1.0f));
        isMoving = true;
    }
}
```

I need to know the direction in order to flip the sprite in a right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell which direction `Mathf.PingPong` is moving by using `Mathf.Repeat` with the same `t` and twice the `length` you are using for `PingPong` then checking if the result is less than or greater than `length`:

```
float pingPongT = Time.time * speed;
float pingPongLength = 1.0f;
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pos1, pos2, Mathf.PingPong(pingPongT, pingPongLength));

float repeatedPingPong = Mathf.Repeat(pingPongT, pingPongLength * 2f);

if (repeatedPingPong < pingPongLength) 
{
    // result of PingPong is increasing or just about to start increasing
} 
else 
{
    // result of PingPong is decreasing or just about to start decreasing
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! And I've learned another mathf. function. Thanks!